# Fonts problem - file titles appear as lines instead of text

Tags: fonts, 16.10

What happened to the titles here?

[image]

Comment: What font are you using? It seems you're using non default font

Comment: How did you get here any background to help us help you ?

Comment: I think it has something to do with `Universal Access`. You can see the icon of `Universal Access` on the left end of upper right corner. Check your settings for `Universal Access`.

Comment: anwar i tried many fonts , George which background ?  Manish Kumar Bisht I did not find any setting their